# Pandas decode is slow on large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a very large dataset loaded into pandas, and I'm trying to use the `[column].str.decode` function on the entire column but it's proving to be very slow (couple of seconds of loading).

Is there any way to speed up this process?

Comment: May we have an example of the data please for debugging?

Comment: `decode` is a string method, and has to be applied individually to each (byte)string in the Series.  `pandas` stores strings in an `object` dtype array as Python strings.

Comment: We can't help much without seeing your data and what you want to get out of it.